# R Shiny - Right-aligning action button in collapsible menuItem causing ghosting effect?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard with three collapsible menu items in the sidebar menu. The first menu item contains an action button that I am trying to right-align. When the menu item is expanded, the button is visible but overflows onto the label of the second menu item:

[image]

What's causing this effect and how can I go about fixing it?

Here is the code to reproduce the app:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

header = dashboardHeader()

sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(

    menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "item1", 

             selectInput("letters", "Letters:", choices = LETTERS),

             tags$div(class = "pull-right", 
                      actionButton("clickme", label = "Click me", style = "primary")
             )

    ), 

    menuItem("Item 2"), 
    menuItem("Item 3")

  )
)
body = dashboardBody()

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input,output,session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Replacing `class = "pull-right"` with `style = "float:right;"` has the same effect.

Adding this style:

```
.skin-blue .sidebar-menu>li>.treeview-menu {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

seems to get rid of the ghosting problem but adds a scroll to the overflow portion of the selectInput dropdown, which I don't want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the `action button` to the right we can do `CSS` similar to [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/vgeURRSDScA)

```
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "item1",
             selectInput("letters", "Letters:", choices = LETTERS),
             actionButton("clickme", label = "Click me", style = "primary"),
             tags$style(type='text/css', "button#clickme {margin-left: 60%;}")), 
    menuItem("Item 2"), 
    menuItem("Item 3")
  )
)
```

Alternatively

```
menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "item1",
             selectInput("letters", "Letters:", choices = LETTERS),
             div(style="display:inline-block;margin-left: 52%;padding-bottom: 10px;",
                 actionButton("clickme", label = "Click me", style = "primary"))
```

Comment: Using `button#clickme {margin-left: 60%;}` without the pull-right class solves the ghosting but there is no margin between the button and menuItem 2. `button#clickme {margin-left: 60%; margin-bottom:15px;}` did not work because the space that gets added to the bottom of the button still spills over onto menuItem 2. The added space also has the same colour as the background of menuItem 2, not the lighter grey that you see when a menuItem is expanded.